# Import CSV into a new table -MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to import CSV files located in a folder into Access as new tables and I have been trying with a code

```
Public Const rootdir = "C:\Users\deb670s\Desktop\importcsv"

Sub import()
Dim nr As Integer
Dim file As AcBrowseToObjectType
file = Dir$(rootdir & "*.csv")
nr = 1
Do While file <> ""
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "ImportSpec", "NewTableName-" & nr, rootdir & file, True, , msoEncodingCentralEuropean
file = Dir$
nr = nr + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

But I get an error saying variable not defined at **msoEncodingCentralEuropean** Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Access does not know anything about the `msoEncodingCentralEuropean` constant unless you add a reference to the *Microsoft Office Object Library*.  Or you could use the constant's value, 1250, instead of the constant's name.

Comment: I did so but now I get the error type mismatch on the line file = Dir$(rootdir & "*.csv").

Comment: OK, that's a different error.  So now what is `importcsv` in `C:\Users\deb670s\Desktop\importcsv`?  If that is the name of the folder which contains the CSV files, do this: `Public Const rootdir = "C:\Users\deb670s\Desktop\importcsv\"`

Comment: Yes I had modified it but the error remains the same ?

Comment: `AcBrowseToObjectType` is the name of an enum.  You need `Dim file As String`  instead.

Comment: Ok now its another error on the line  DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "ImportSpec", "NewTableName-" & nr, rootdir & file, True, , 1250.  The text file specification ImportSec does not exist. You cannot import, export, or link using the specification.

Comment: Either create the import specification or remove it from your `TransferText` line.

Comment: I have removed the Importspec specification name Now I get the error Run-time error '2521': You have specified a Transfer Type that doesn't support the HTML Table Name arguement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hummmm...  I think you should try it this way.

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm#ImpAllWktsSepTbl

Just change the XLS to CSV.

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter must be a CodePage value:

[Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: What is a Code Page identifier? and where should I add it?

Comment: It is the last parameter of `DoCmd.TransferText`.